# Testing a Consumer is failing when use database_sync_to_async Djagno Channels

Tags: python-3.x, django, asynchronous, django-channels, django-4.1

So, I didn't use channels for a very long time, so let's be that this is a first time that I have tried to do something.

I am trying to create 1 Consumer, wrapped with 1 custom Auth middleware and I want to test my Consumer, if it behaves properly in various test cases.

```
Django==4.1.7
channels==4.0.0
```

*middleware.py*

```
@database_sync_to_async
def get_user(email):
    user = User.objects.get(email=email)
    if not user.is_active:
        raise AuthenticationFailed("User is inactive", code="user_inactive")
    return user


class OktaASGIMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, inner):
        super().__init__(inner)
        self.okta_auth = OKTAAuthentication()

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        try:
            # token checking and retrieval 
            claims = self.okta_auth.jwt_verifier.parse_token(token)[1]
            user = await get_user(claims["email"])
            scope["user"] = user
        except Exception as exc:
            await send({"type": "websocket.close"})
            raise
        return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
```

*tests.py*

```
    @aioresponses()
    async def test_connect_with_correct_token_edit_resource_draft(
        self, mocked_io_request
    ):
        mocked_io_request.get(
            # mocked request/respones
        )

        communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(
            application, f"/ws/draft/1/?token={sometoken}"
        )
        connected, subprotocol = await communicator.connect()
        self.assertTrue(connected)
```

So, the issue is, when I use `database_sync_to_async` as Docs suggests, I am getting:

`django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed`.

When I use `from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async`, everything works fine and I can test my consumer properly.

Also, i an attempt to avoid `database_sync_to_async`, I switched from `JsonWebsocketConsumer` to `AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer`, but still no help.

NOTE: Both of this code works well when the app is running and you connect to Websocket through Browser extension or using Javascript.

What's missing here, and why I can't make tests work with `database_sync_to_async` and with `JsonWebsocketConsumer`?

I do not want to have a lot of created connections, and I want to use `database_sync_to_async` as Docs suggest.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.

So the issue was that in my `TestCase` I inherited `TestCase` from `django.test`.

Testing django channels and consumers with `TestCase`, won't work. For async support, it should be used `TransactionTestCase`,
which provides better support for asynchronous code.

`TransactionTestCase` wraps each test method in a database transaction, and since it also supports asynchronous code, it can be used for testing Django Channels without the issues associated with `TestCase`.

Comment: This solved the problem on MacOS, but I still have issue on Linux. Tests are still getting stuck on ubuntu image, can anyone help? :)